# Typescript error with renderProp enzyme function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, types, enzyme, typescript-generics

I have created a `RestrictedRoute` react typescript component.
It should redirect to /dashboard page when the user is connected and page is restricted. If not it return a Route with the component passed in props.

`RestrictedRoute.tsx` :

```
interface Props {
  component: ComponentType;
  restricted?: boolean;
}

const RestrictedRoute = ({ component: Component, restricted, ...rest }: Props & RouteProps) => {
  const { data: userConnected, error } = useSWR('userConnected', checkUserLogged);

  if (userConnected !== undefined) {
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) =>
          userConnected && restricted && !error ? (
            <Redirect to={ROUTES.DASHBOARD} />
          ) : (
            <Component {...props} />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  }

  if (error) return <Redirect to={ROUTES.LOGIN} />;

  return <LoadingPage />;
};

export default RestrictedRoute;
```

I want to test it with jest and enzyme. So I have created the following test.
It tests that the render prop return component passed in prop.

`RestrictedRoute.test.tsx`:

```
interface RestrictedRouteProps {
  component: ComponentType;
}

describe('RestrictedRoute', () => {
  const props: RestrictedRouteProps = {
    component: () => <></>,
  };
  const mockUseSwr = useSWR as jest.Mock;
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockUseSwr.mockClear();
  });

it('should return Component when data fetched and user not connected', () => {
    const userConnected = false;
    const fakePath = '/youhou';
    mockUseSwr.mockReturnValueOnce({ data: userConnected });
    const wrapper = shallow(<RestrictedRoute component={props.component} path={fakePath} />)
      .find(Route)
      .renderProp('render')();
    expect(wrapper.find(props.component)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
```

The test is working but I have the following typescript error at compilation :

`Argument of type '"render"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"children"'.`

When I replace `.renderProp('render')();` with `.renderProp<RouteProps>('render')();` I see another error : `Type 'RouteProps' does not satisfy the constraint '"children"'`

Can you help me with this please ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that use RouteProps typing and route components props mock for renderProp argument (mandatory because render function from react-router-dom need this in his typescript definition)  :

```
const routeComponentPropsMock = {
    history: {} as any,
    location: {} as any,
    match: {} as any,
  };

it.only('should return Component when data fetched and user not connected', () => {
    const userConnected = false;
    const fakePath = '/youhou';
    mockUseSwr.mockReturnValueOnce({ data: userConnected });
    const wrapper = shallow(<RestrictedRoute component={props.component} path={fakePath} />);
    const routeWrapper = wrapper.find<RouteProps>(Route).renderProp('render')(
      routeComponentPropsMock,
    );
    expect(routeWrapper.find(props.component)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
```